# Making sql query to retrieve data from sqlite database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have my database set up with 4 tables. All tables have same no of columns and their column names slightly differ.Like in one table if it is ZCARBOHYDRATES then in another table it is ZCARBOHYDRATES_PER_SERVING.

On a view controller, I have a search bar. On typing in the search bar, search query works, retrieves data from database and populates a tableview.

**Until now search query works as follows:**

If a user types Mozzarella Cheese(Whole Milk), then

1. select all the records that containing the search text 'Mozzarella Cheese(Whole Milk)'
2. select the records that contain Mozzarella + select the records that contain Cheese + select the records that contain Whole + select the records that contain Milk are retrieved.

Now result of 1. is 'union' with all the records that contain Mozzarella 'union' all the records that contain 'Cheese' 'union' all the records that contain 'Whole' 'union' all the records that contain 'Milk'.

**Code:**

```
-(NSArray *)getFilteredRecordsUsingSearchText:(NSString *)searchText
{

    NSMutableArray *searchArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //for first table
    NSMutableString *queryForRecipe = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@" select ZCODE as code , ZRECIPE_TITLE as title , ZFAT_PER_SERVING as fat , ZFIBER_PER_SERVING as fiber , ZPROTEIN_PER_SERVING as protien , ZSUGARS_PER_SERVING as sugar , ZCARBOHYDRATES_PER_SERVING as carbs , ZCALORIES_PER_SERVING as calories ,  ZSERVINGS as servingSize , ZSERVING_SIZE_DESCRIPTION_1 as servingUnit , 'ZRECIPES' as TableName from ZRECIPES  where title like '%%%@%%' ",searchText];//retrieving data according to point 1
    NSArray *seprateSearchText = [searchText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    for (NSString *str in seprateSearchText) {

         if (str.length>2) {
            [queryForRecipe appendFormat:@" union select ZCODE as code , ZRECIPE_TITLE as title , ZFAT_PER_SERVING as fat , ZFIBER_PER_SERVING as fiber , ZPROTEIN_PER_SERVING as protien , ZSUGARS_PER_SERVING as sugar , ZCARBOHYDRATES_PER_SERVING as carbs , ZCALORIES_PER_SERVING as calories ,  ZSERVINGS as servingSize , ZSERVING_SIZE_DESCRIPTION_1 as servingUnit , 'ZRECIPES' as TableName from ZRECIPES  where title like '%%%@%%' ",str];
        }
    }//retrieving data according to point 2


//for second table
NSMutableString *queryForAddedRecipe=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@" select ZCODE as code , ZRECIPE_TITLE as title , ZFAT_PER_SERVING as fat , ZFIBER_PER_SERVING as fiber , ZPROTEIN_PER_SERVING as protien , ZSUGARS_PER_SERVING as sugar , ZCARBOHYDRATES_PER_SERVING as carbs , ZCALORIES_PER_SERVING as calories ,  ZSERVINGS as servingSize , ZSERVING_SIZE_DESCRIPTION_1 as servingUnit , 'ZADDED_RECIPE' as TableName from ZADDED_RECIPE  where title like '%%%@%%' ",searchText];//retrieving data according to point 1

for (NSString *str in seprateSearchText) {
     if (str.length>2) {
    [queryForAddedRecipe appendFormat:@" union select ZCODE as code , ZRECIPE_TITLE as title , ZFAT_PER_SERVING as fat , ZFIBER_PER_SERVING as fiber , ZPROTEIN_PER_SERVING as protien , ZSUGARS_PER_SERVING as sugar , ZCARBOHYDRATES_PER_SERVING as carbs , ZCALORIES_PER_SERVING as calories ,  ZSERVINGS as servingSize , ZSERVING_SIZE_DESCRIPTION_1 as servingUnit , 'ZRECIPES' as TableName from ZRECIPES  where title like '%%%@%%' ",str];
     }
}//retrieving data according to point 2


//for third table
NSMutableString *queryForUSDAFood=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"  select ZCODE as code , ZFOOD_ITEM as title , ZFAT as fat , ZFIBER as fiber , ZPROTEIN as protien , ZSUGARS as sugar , ZCARBOHYDRATE as carbs , ZCALORIES as calories ,   ZSERVING_DESC_1 as servingSize , ZSERVING_SIZE_DESC_1 as servingUnit  ,'ZUSDA_FOODS' as TableName from ZUSDA_FOODS  where  title like '%%%@%%' ",searchText];//retrieving data according to point 1



for (NSString *str in seprateSearchText) {

    if (str.length>2) {
        [queryForUSDAFood appendFormat:@" union select ZCODE as code , ZFOOD_ITEM as title , ZFAT as fat , ZFIBER as fiber , ZPROTEIN as protien , ZSUGARS as sugar , ZCARBOHYDRATE as carbs , ZCALORIES as calories ,   ZSERVING_DESC_1 as servingSize , ZSERVING_SIZE_DESC_1 as servingUnit  ,'ZUSDA_FOODS' as TableName from ZUSDA_FOODS  where  title like '%%%@%%'  ",str];
    }
}//retrieving data according to point 2


//for fourth table
NSMutableString *queryForAddedFood=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@" select ZCODE as code , ZFOOD_ITEM as title , ZFAT_PER_SERVING as fat , ZFIBER_PER_SERVING as fiber , ZPROTEIN_PER_SERVING as protien , ZSUGARS_PER_SERVING as sugar , ZCARBOHYDRATES_PER_SERVING as carbs , ZCALORIES_PER_SERVING as calories , ZSERVING_SIZE_1 as servingSize , ZSERVING_UNIT_1 as servingUnit , 'ZADDED_FOOD_ITEMS' as TableName from ZADDED_FOOD_ITEMS  where  title like '%%%@%%' ",searchText];//retrieving data according to point 1



for (NSString *str in seprateSearchText) {

     if (str.length>2) {

    [queryForAddedFood appendFormat:@" union select ZCODE as code , ZFOOD_ITEM as title , ZFAT_PER_SERVING as fat , ZFIBER_PER_SERVING as fiber , ZPROTEIN_PER_SERVING as protien , ZSUGARS_PER_SERVING as sugar , ZCARBOHYDRATES_PER_SERVING as carbs , ZCALORIES_PER_SERVING as calories , ZSERVING_SIZE_1 as servingSize , ZSERVING_UNIT_1 as servingUnit , 'ZADDED_FOOD_ITEMS' as TableName from ZADDED_FOOD_ITEMS  where  title like '%%%@%%' ",str];

     }
}//retrieving data according to point 2


NSString *combineQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ union %@ union %@ union %@ ORDER BY title ASC ",queryForRecipe,queryForAddedRecipe,queryForUSDAFood,queryForAddedFood];
```

........
........
//rest is all about preparing sql statements...

**What has to be done now?**

Now search query has to be changed to meet the following conditions:

1.If the search term contains multiple words, for example “chicken breast” search results should contain both words in the title of the item, including plural form like “chicken breasts”. Or “apples” if search is for “apple”, etc.

2.Punctuation marks (‘, -, /, …) and articles (the, and, an) should be disregarded (for example, “chicken (breast or wing…) would  first return all 3 words. Next, any 2 words. Finally any 1 word.

I'm looking for assistance to form the query matching the above criterion (especially finding it hard to meet point 2.).